# Understanding data availability for zk rollups

Tags: blockchain, calldata, layer-2, zero-knowledge, rollups

My understanding is that if a zkrollup operator suddenly ceases operation, you have to sync the rollup’s history from genesis to get the current state. In other words, if the transaction data has been posted to 500 ethereum blocks, you would need all the data from all 500 blocks to recreate current state. Is this correct?

If that's correct, how do we make sense of Ethereum's eventual plan to only make data available for a few weeks and then prune? Wouldn't the data need to be made available indefinitely (because you need all data from genesis to recreate the zkrollup state)?

Any help here would be appreciated.